# time data ' 23:59' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M'

Tags: python, django

Why do I get that error?
This is my forms.py:

```
class filtrosEntrada(forms.Form):
    fechaInicio = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),required=True,label='Fecha de inicio: ')
    fechaFin = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),required=True,label='Fecha final ')
```

This is my views.py

```
def reporte_salida_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated(): # se genera el reporte pdf con los datos necesarios
        if request.method == "POST":
            fechaInicio = datetime.strptime(request.POST['fechaInicio']+' 00:00',"%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
            fechaFin = datetime.strptime(request.POST['fechaFin']+' 23:59',"%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

And finally my template.html

```
<form id='formularioEntrada' action="." method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-md-3">
        {{ form.fechaInicio.label_tag}}
        {{ form.fechaInicio}}<br>
        {{ form.fechaInicio.errors}}
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-3">  
        {{ form.fechaFin.label_tag}}  
        {{ form.fechaFin}}  
       </div>  
</form>
```

The error is this line

```
fechaFin = datetime.strptime(request.POST['fechaFin']+' 23:59',"%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

I am using python 2.7 and Django 1.6

Answer (score 1):

You get that error when `request.POST['fechaFin']` is an empty string; e.g. the form field was cleared:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime(' 23:59', "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data ' 23:59' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M'
```